# Change markers/icons from tab space on GtkSourceView

Tags: python, gtk, gedit, gtksourceview

How can I change (if I can) These icons/markers? I could not find any docs about that!

[image]

I'm using python, and custom scheme style, but any idea can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the glyphs are hardcoded into the library: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/tree/gtksourceview/gtksourceview.c#n2284

I assume you already know you can turn them off altogether with `view.props.draw_spaces = 0`. It looks like you can't modify them, though.

Comment: it's bad, because it's very ugly. I would like to make more subtle, like [this](http://imgur.com/FgoOKXe). Any advise?

Comment: Open a bug on bugzilla.gnome.org and submit a patch to gtksourceview that allows customizing the markers. For example, with CSS classes and `-gtk-icon-theme` CSS properties.